# PCRE To Get Date from middle of string

Tags: php, regex, pcre

The string:

```
Destiny 2 12_9_2017 8_08_31 PM.mp4
```

All these strings will have 5 parts.

1. Game
2. Date
3. Time
4. AM/PM
5. Extension

How would I regex to get the date and time (separately, 2 separate functions) when the game can vary greatly (various length, spaces, colons, hyphens in the title).

For example, it would have to work with all of these strings.

```
Destiny 2 12_9_2017 8_08_31 PM.mp4
Assassin's Creed: Origins 12_9_2017 8_08_31 PM.mp4
Ori and the Blind Forest - Definitive Edition 12_9_2017 8_08_31 PM.mp4
```

And be able to get the date (which isn't padded with 0's) from that string no matter the game.

Comment: That's a very simple regex. Have you made any attempt to learn it?

Comment: Something like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/qi9rP0/2)

Answer (score 1):

I would define the following functions:

```
function getGameDate($input) {
    preg_match('/(\d+_\d+_\d{4})\s+\d+_\d+_\d+/', $input, $re);
    return $re[1];
}

function getGameTime($input) {
    preg_match('/\d+_\d+_\d{4}\s+([^.]*)/', $input, $re);
    return $re[1];
}

print(getGameDate("Destiny 2 12_9_2017 8_08_31 PM.mp4") . "\n");
print(getGameTime("Destiny 2 12_9_2017 8_08_31 PM.mp4") . "\n");
print(getGameDate("Assassin's Creed: Origins 12_9_2017 8_08_31 PM.mp4") . "\n");
print(getGameTime("Assassin's Creed: Origins 12_9_2017 8_08_31 PM.mp4") . "\n");
print(getGameDate("Ori and the Blind Forest - Definitive Edition 12_9_2017 8_08_31 PM.mp4"));
print(getGameTime("Ori and the Blind Forest - Definitive Edition 12_9_2017 8_08_31 PM.mp4"));
```

Nothing magical happening here, except that you'll notice that I match both the date *and* time, then capture only the former.  This is deliberate, because both the date and time have the general pattern of 3 numbers separated by underscores.  We need to make sure we capture the right one, so by including both we cover this edge case.

### Demo

Comment: If you want to capture AM/PM information also, you could modify like this: `(\d+_\d+_\d{4})\s+(\d+_\d+_\d+ (?:AM|PM))`

Comment: @MateuszMarchel The OP seems to be asking for the date, not the time, nor the AM/PM quantity.  But my answer could easily be extended to do this, if needed.

Comment: Question is: "How would I regex to get the date and time"

Comment: @MateuszMarchel Answer updated to also fish out the time.  Note that it's actually easy to get the time; we can just grab everything after the date which is not a period.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this pattern

```
$str = 'Destiny 2 12_9_2017 8_08_31 PM.mp4';
preg_match('/\d+\S+ \d+\S+ [A|P]M/', $str, $date_time);
echo $date_time[0];

// Or with this '/((\d+\S+){3}\s){2}[A|P]M/'
```